# Script all data out of a single table or all tables in Sql Server 2005/8?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Simple question here, and I know there are lots of kludgy ways to do it :)

But I was hoping a SQL server expert had a script to easily script all the data out of a table?  Or possibly all the tables in a DB?

I'm getting tired of copying and pasting data over RDC! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar requirement.

To script insert statements for each row in a table.  Sometimes I needed the Identity column, other times I did not.

So, I wrote this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GenerateInsertScripts] (
    @tableName varchar(100),
    @tableSchema varchar(50) = 'dbo',
    @skipIdentity bit = 1
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @columnName varchar(800)
    DECLARE @columnType varchar(20)
    DECLARE @statementA varchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @statementB varchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @statement nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @isIdentity bit
    DECLARE @commaFlag bit

    SET @statementA = 'INSERT INTO [' + @tableSchema + '].[' + @tableName + '] ('
    SET @statementB = ''' + '

    DECLARE cols CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        COLUMN_NAME,
        DATA_TYPE,
        (SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[' + @tableSchema + '].[' + @tableName + ']'),
        information_schema.columns.COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity')) AS IsIdentity
    FROM
        information_schema.columns
    WHERE
        TABLE_NAME = @tableName
      AND
        TABLE_SCHEMA = @tableSchema
    ORDER BY
        ORDINAL_POSITION

    OPEN cols
    FETCH cols INTO @columnName, @columnType, @isIdentity 
    SET @commaFlag = 0
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF NOT (@isIdentity = 1 AND @skipIdentity = 1) BEGIN
        IF @commaFlag = 1 BEGIN
            SET @statementA = @statementA + ', '
            SET @statementB = @statementB + ' + '', '' + '
        END
        SET @commaFlag = 1

        SET @statementA = @statementA + '[' + @columnName + ']'
        SET @statementB = @statementB + 'CASE WHEN [' + @columnName + '] IS NULL THEN ''NULL'' ELSE ' + 
        CASE
            WHEN @columnType = 'bigint' OR @columnType = 'int' OR @columnType = 'tinyint' OR @columnType = 'bit' THEN
                'CAST([' + @columnName + '] AS varchar(MAX))'
            WHEN @columnType = 'datetime' THEN
                ''''''''' + CONVERT(varchar, [' + @columnName + '], 121) + '''''''''
            ELSE
                ''''''''' + REPLACE(CAST([' + @columnName + '] AS varchar(MAX)), '''''''', '''''''''''') + '''''''''
        END

         + ' END'
        END
    FETCH cols INTO @columnName, @columnType, @isIdentity
    END
    SET @commaFlag = 0
    CLOSE cols
    DEALLOCATE cols

    SET @statementB = @statementB + ' + '''

    SET @statement = 'SELECT ''' + @statementA + ') VALUES (' + @statementB + ')'' [Statement] FROM [' + @tableSchema + '].[' + @tableName + ']'

    EXEC sp_executesql @statement
END
```

Comment: Thank you sir, exactly what I needed!  You get the answer vote because the code is here and clear as day :)

Comment: +1, how can you have the "correct" answer bu no a single up vote?? I hate when that happens to me, so +1 to you!

Comment: +1! Cmon guys, +1 this answer! Helped me a lot too, as I'm not a SQL specialist, I was thinking how I'd do that, how I'd interact with sys tables, but there, you already did it! Thanks a lot John.

Answer (score 3):

use this great script:

http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code.htm#inserts

but this is a bad way to move data, good to help fix a problem or move a little test data etc.

Comment: Depending on whose environment he is using, it may be his only way to move data.  I had to use my method below to get data off of GoDaddy's servers.

Comment: KM, I agree, but John, is spot on.  It's the only way I can see to move the data easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving data to a differnt database or some sort of file, use SSIS. IF the task is not complex, use the wizard, right click onthe datbasename, go to taks and choose Export data.

If you are doing the whole database an alternative is to simply restore the latest backup in the other location.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2008 you can use the `Script Data` option in the Generate Scripts wizard. Not for 2005 though.

You can start the wizard by right clicking on a database in the Object Explorer in SSMS, and then `Tasks` -> `Generate Scripts...`.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2005, you can use the free [Database Publishing Wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=56e5b1c5-bf17-42e0-a410-371a838e570a&displaylang=en) from Microsoft.